# Positioning custom arrows in bxSlider

Tags: html, css, slider, position, bxslider

I implemented custom arrows for bxslider per this Github answer: [BX Slider custom controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081994/bx-slider-custom-controls)

I'm looking to place the arrows on top of the slider images, though, and having difficulty implementing this.

What it looks like now:
[image]
What I want:
[image]

I've tried applying position: relative to .bxNext, and position: absolute to .slider, but that didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slider').bxSlider({
      auto: true,
      pause: 3000,
       mode: 'fade',
       speed: 1200, 
      pager: false,
      controls: true,
           nextSelector: '.bxNext',
     prevSelector: '.bxPrev',  
          nextText: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right fa-3x"></i>',
     prevText: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-3x"></i>'
});
    });


.bxNext {
  float: right;
}





  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<section class="conC"> 


  <ul class="slider" style="padding:0px !important;">



    <li><img src="img/image1.png">
    <div class="caption1"><p>image1</p></div>
    </li>

    <li> <img src="img/image2.png">
    <div class="caption2"><p> image2 </p> </div>
    <div class="caption3">caption </div>
    </li>

  <li><img src="img/image3.png">
    <div class="caption1"><p>image3</p></div>
    </li>

 </ul>



  <div class='controls'>
    <a href='#' id='PREV' class='bxPrev'></a>
    <a href='#' id='NEXT' class='bxNext'></a>
  </div>



</section>
```

Comment: The answer is not what you were looking for?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It is - much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position the arrows absolute inside a slider wrapper that has a relative positioning.

I set up an example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5L8mjd4h/)

```
.controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

Hope this helps you further.

Comment: I've had to tweak your code to position the arrows horizonatally.     e.g. #PREV {
  left: 20%;
} didn't work.  I'm having trouble vertically aligning arrows now, would you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64406585/translatey-50-does-not-center-things-exactly

Comment: If you want to move arrows more inwards, use margins: https://jsfiddle.net/8jtm7drw/